# Vmware Fusion - No USB Devices on macOS 10.13 High Sierra

Tags: vmware

No USB devices or the internal memory card reader appear in any VMWare Fusion guests.

There are posts suggesting that it's necessary to Allow vmware fusion in Security & Privacy Settings, but I have been unable to trigger the prompt to allow vmware fusion in the Security & Privacy panel in settings.

These are the links that I've been trying to follow:

[Vmware Community: VMware Fusion 11.1 USB Connection Odyssey](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/VMware-Fusion-11-1-USB-Connection-Odyssey/td-p/444472)

[Vmware Community: NO USB](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/NO-USB/m-p/1402169?ru=3801879&sr=inbox)

[Vmware Community: USB devices no longer recognised on VMWare Fusion 10](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/USB-devices-no-longer-recognised-on-VMWare-Fusion-10/m-p/1427743)

Update: Reverting to VMware fusion 8.5 did not resolve the issue - it displays the same behaviour as VMware 11.5 . VMware fusion 8.5 was able to access USB devices under macOS 10.12 Yosemite without any issues.

Macbook Pro 11,3

macOS 10.13.6

Vmware Fusion 11.5, 8.5

Comment: You are using macOS 10.13.6, but the [system requirements](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/11/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-84E34BF1-92A2-4B86-9995-70893A9B04A9.html) for VMware Fusion 11 state macOS 10.14 or later for the host OS.

Comment: @DavidAnderson High Sierra 10.13.x is supported as high as VMware Fusion 11.5 . VMWare fusion >=11.5.5 requires macOS 10.14 https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2088571 . Generally the build target is set as this when VMWare publish their applications, so incompatible apps fail to attempt to open rather than behave unexpectedly.